# Windows 2019 and PHP 7.3: "session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir failed: No such file or directory (2)"

Tags: php, windows, iis, permissions, fastcgi

Having this problem. I know there is similar questions, but none of them provided a solution.

- Windows Server 2019 server core
- PHP 7.3.7 x64 under IIS.

Error message:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: session_start():
>   ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(D:\TempPHP) failed: No such file or
>   directory (2).

- The directory does exists and it is full of sessions files.
- There is FULL permissions (I know, security risk, but I'm first trying to make it work) for the application pool user (IIS AppPool...), IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, LOCAL SERVICE, LOCAL NETWORK, SYSTEM and CREATE OWNER.
- The error message seems to shows randomly.

Some relevant php.ini settings:

```
session.gc_probability = 1
error_log = "D:\TempPHP\PHP73x64_errors.log"
upload_tmp_dir = "D:\TempPHP\upload"
session.save_path = "D:\TempPHP"
sys_temp_dir = "D:\TempPHP"
```

edit: "D:\" is a local partition. Not a mapped or a shared drive. Logs and sessions are being written successfully. It seems that php just can't remove those files.

Comment: What kind of disc is D:\? Mapped drive?

Comment: make sure that the iis application pool is using the application pool identity and assign the session_start(). assign the iis_iusr and iis_iusrs full control permission. and the folder is not mapped or share drive.

Comment: @LexLi it is a local drive. Same disc as C:\, just another partition.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal it is configured as "ApplicationPoolIdentity" on the "identity" option. The folder is not mapped nor a share. There is not a iis_iusr user avaliable. Did you mean just iusr? iusr and iis_iusrs already have full control permisson.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by "Logs and sessions are being written successfully. It seems that php just can't remove those files."?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal If I open up the directory (D:\TempPHP), there is data in the PHP log (PHP73x64_errors.log) and PHP is successfully writing session data there (there is a lot of sess_xxxxxxx files). But the error message says "opendir(D:\TempPHP) failed: No such file or directory". How there is "no such file or directory" if it is writing data on that directory??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found out the problem.

Seems like that with windows the session.save_path cannot be in a different disk / partition from the PHP executable path. In my case PHP directory was c:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3, so I moved the TempPHP folder from D: to C: partition and changed the value of session.save_path from "D:\TempPHP" to "C:\TempPHP". Now the sess_xxxxx files are automatically cleaned up and there is no more error messages.

Don't know if this holds true for others php or windows versions.